# How to remove invallid entries from macro list?

Tags: excel, vba

In Excel, when opening the list of macros, there are some invalid entries. How to get rid of them?

Background:
I have an extended VBA library, containing a lot of UDFs and subs. I have added descriptions for UDFs using macro options. Maybe i created these invalid entries accidently in the past by a sub, which parses my code modules and generates descriptions for UDFs if this is provided via comments in the code module. This works fine now.

The invalid entries are actually the names of UDFs which do not exist anymore. They should not have appeared unter macros at any time, but again, maybe I messed up in the past.

I also would like to add some description to macros that do exist - but apparently that is only possible for UDFs?

Clarifications:

- There is only this one workbook open. These are not macros of a different workbook. I selected "This Workbook only" for list of macros anyway.
- There are no addins.
- In VBE under Macros these invalid entires do NOT appear.
- In Excel, under Developer Tools->Macros they DO appear.
- In Excel, under Developer Tools->Macros, I can not edit or delete or execute these entries. Delete is greyed out, edit and execute lead to a popup error saying: "Der Bezug ist ungültig."

Comment: Where exactly do you see the list with invalid entries? Can you post a screenshot?

Comment: I see it in Excel under Macros. I do not see them in VBA Editor under Macros. Will add screenshot tomorrow.

Answer (score 0):

If you are referring to the Macro dialog that opens when clicking View > Macros, then note that there is a drop-down with which you can filter to show macros from a particular workbook only.

Use this to find where the "invalid" macros live, then edit that workbook and handle the macros from there (fix them or remove them).

[image]

Comment: I only have this one workbook open. Delete button is disabled. If I hit edit, I get an error about the reference being invalid. I open the "Macros" dialog via developer tools (I hope I have the name right, I'm on a system in German).

Comment: Deutsch ist kein Problem. What happens if you open the VBE? What projects do you see there? Do you have any Add-ins installed? These could be the source for macros and if the add-ins have not been coded properly, they could be the reason. Try starting Excel in Safe Mode, which will not load any add-ins and see what you get then. Remove Add-ins and check again.

Comment: In VBE under Macros it is not listed. Addin in VBE: The meni lists no items.

Answer (score 0):

The Macro dialog box that opens from the Developer tab lists all macros in "All open workbooks" by default. In the dropdown that shows this selection you can select to show macros in only a specific workbook. The reverse of this coin is that you can know exactly where any listed macro is located.

There are buttons to the right of the list which allow you to *Edit* or *Delete* any of the listed macros. The *Edit* button will take you to the module where the macro is stored.

There is also an *Options* button. When you click that another dialog box opens where you can set shortcuts as well as add a description. You can add a description to any listed macro, whether it's used as UDF or otherwise.

I wonder what would happen if a description exists for a macro that has been deleted. If such a situation is supported by Excel pressing the *Delete* button should rectify it.

Comment: Well, as described, there is only one workbook open. The Delete and Edit Buttons do not lead me to code but bring that error message of Reference invalid. It is not a question of this macro not existing in THIS workbook, it exists in no workbook that is open (which, again is only one).

Answer (score 0):

I found an answer on microsoft.com:
https://answers.microsoft.com/en-us/msoffice/forum/msoffice_excel-mso_winother-mso_2016/cannot-delete-macros/8e9072ae-ad95-49cb-952c-3a50b746d0d2

So it appears my workbook got somehow "corrupted". As I said, I did play with it quite a bit during development. So what I did to fix it:

1. Export all code modules.
2. Save workbook as .xlsx under a different name.
3. Open this cleaned xlsx and save it as xlsm again.
4. Imported all code modules into this cleaned xlsm.
5. Manually copied code in worksheet from corrupted version to clean version.

Now the macros are gone in the cleaned version.